# Checking up remotely on Website Usage

Tags: web, usage-statistics

A client of mine has a pure HTML website that was built in the dark ages - they want me to find where their users are coming from, how many individual users there are, etc.

They want to know if the site is being used enough for them to invest the money into renovating it.

I am remote from their site and do not have access to their web server.

Is there something like ComScore for small sites that I can go into to check their usage statistics?

Answer (score 0):

You will either have to get them to send you their server logs, or ask them to give you access to their hosting account, which may have these statistics available (use `whois` to find out where they are hosted).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Analytics with static HTML pages.